# mysql-connector-python is not working on VS Code and working in python shell

Tags: python, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to connect to MySQL database, but strangly
`mysql-connector-python` is working in python shell, and not using VS Code.

I tried installing the following packages:

```
pip install mysql-connector
pip install mysql-connector-python
pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

No luck either. So, I uninstalled all packages then reinstalled only `mysql-connector-python`, then rebooted, to make sure there was no issue in this regard.

The error is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package
```

Python version: 3.9.4
VS Code: 1.6.20

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I ran my python script in terminal (not using code runner), same issue.

Comment: I connected to MySQL using pyodbc package, but still no luck with mysql

Comment: Uninstall `mysql-connector` and `mysql-connector-python-rf`. The official (and maintained) MySQL connector is  `mysql-connector-python`. Also check that you're not using a different Python version in VS Code. In the screenshots I see you're using a custom Python installation and VS Code is using the anaconda3.

Comment: I tried exactly that. Code runner extension is what causing the problem. So, when I execute in terminal my code run smoothly. I believe code runner not connecting to the correct environment. I don't know why yet. Thank you so much for you reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue was related to code runner.
uninstall, then install did the trick.

I often face some error because of code runner not connecting to the right environment or not reading new package.
Normally, restarting the visual studio code session or the whole software solve it, but not in this case.